# Angular 2 RC6: cli-compiler says "function calls are not supported"

Tags: angular, angular2-cli, ng2-translate

When trying to compile my RC6 app using the following command:

```
ngc -p C:\Path\To\Project
```

(I am placed inside `C:\Path\To\Project\node_modules\.bin` when I'm running the command)

I get the following error:

```
Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function (position 20:25 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol CoreModule in C:/Path/To/Project/app/modules/core/core.module.ts
```

This is what it complains about:

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({ 
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (http: Http) => new TranslateStaticLoader(http, 'app/languages', '.json'),
        deps: [Http]
    })
],
```

If I remove `TranslateModule.forRoot...` the error disappears.

How do I replace this with an exported function as the error implies?

Comment: I've came across the same problem. I've tried replacing useFactory: <lambda> with useFactory: <exported function above> with no luck. The issue might be that ng2-translate's devs did not push *.metadata.json files among their .d.ts and .js files. PS: Don't think that the .forRoot() method calls are the issue, ngc can resolve those well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to update ng2-translate to >5.0.0 first of all.
I had the same issue on version ~2.5.0 and exported function did not help.

So your steps:

1. Update version >5.0.0
2. Export function as mentioned by Isaac:

> export function translateStaticLoaderFactory(http: Http) {
>     return new TranslateStaticLoader(http, 'app/languages', '.json');
>   }
>
> @NgModule({
>   imports: [
>       CommonModule,
>       TranslateModule.forRoot({ 
>           provide: TranslateLoader,
>           useFactory: translateStaticLoaderFactory,
>           deps: [Http]
>       })
>   ],

Answer (score 4):

I'm having some luck doing this:

```js
export function translateStaticLoaderFactory(http: Http) {
  return new TranslateStaticLoader(http, 'app/languages', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({ 
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: translateStaticLoaderFactory,
        deps: [Http]
    })
],
```

Comment: I am using exactly the same code - no luck for me :(